# Retrieve specific columns in a csv file efficiently

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to retrieve 7 specific columns in a csv file 100 times for each column. This is what I've been doing. I know it's inefficient, but it seems like it's gonna work if I only know how to append them 100 times.

```
data_file_path = '2001-1.csv'
counter = 0

col0 = []
col1 = []
col2 = []
col13 = []
col16 = []
col17 = []
col18 = []

with open(data_file_path, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as fin:
    splitted = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = ',')
    next(splitted)

    for col in splitted:
        counter += 1
        col0.append(col[0])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0
        col1.append(col[1])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0
        col2.append(col[2])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0            
        col13.append(col[13])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0
        col16.append(col[16])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0
        col17.append(col[17])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0 
        col18.append(col[18])
        if(counter == 100):
            counter = 0
            break

flight_data = [col0, col1, col2, col13, col16, col17, col18]
```

But it would be great to know how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col` here is a misnomer, since you're iterating over rows and cherrypicking columns.

Use a dictionary, and keep a list of columns. You can then reduce your code to a nice little nested loop.

```
idx = [0, 1, 2, 13, 16, 17, 18]
data = {k : [] for k in idx}
with open(data_file_path, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        for i in idx:
            data[i].extend([row[i]] * 100)
```